# how to convert a master cluster to a slave cluster?

Tags: postgresql, replication

I am learning about PostgreSQL streaming replication and so far I have learned how to create a slave cluster using:

```
pg_basebackup -x -R -D main -h host -p port
```

I also have learned that I can promote a slave to be a master like this:

```
pg_ctl -D main promote
```

or

```
pg_ctlcluster 9.4 main promote
```

(if you are working on Ubuntu).

What I like to do now is to say that my previous master is now a slave of the new master. So far I have learned that I can do it by removing the data directory of server, and running `pg_basebackup` again. This means that I have to wait until all of my files are copied back from the new master the old one, which means a lot of data traffic.

Is there another way to do the same thing without copying all the data again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***This means that I have to wait until all of my files are copied back from the new master the old one, which means a lot of data traffic***

When using `pg_basebackup`, yes.

But, if you're confident that the existing files at the destination are almost identical to the source, `rsync` may be used. The rsync remote-update protocol is able to identify what parts of files changed to minimize the amount of data to transfer.

See examples of uses on the postgres wiki: [Binary Replication Tutorial / Starting Replication with only a Quick Master Restart](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Binary_Replication_Tutorial#Starting_Replication_with_only_a_Quick_Master_Restart)

My personal experience with `rsync` versus `pg_basebackup` is that `rsync` is good if the "new master" has not drifted that much from the state when it became master, like a few minutes of transactions on a moderately busy system. Otherwise it still works but `pg_basebackup` appears to be faster.

Comment: Just to be sure by `pg_backup` you mean `pg_basebackup` or I can use `pg_backup` to resync master and slaves ?

Comment: @Beatles1692: `pg_basebackup`, edited to fix.